# Listing Splunk saved searches

Tags: c#, splunk

This is my first post here. I'm sure this topic is old, but I do not seem to find any solution for my problem.

I'm trying to design a Windows Form application (c#) in which the user can connect to a Splunk instance and perform a few actions, among others getting a list of existing saved searches.

I'm using "Splunk.client" and no issues with connection or executing a search. But no matter what I try, I can't get the list of existing saved searches.

Is this even possible? Any of you guys have any tips.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

The REST command `/services/saved/searches` will return a list of existing saved searches, however, the user invoking the command must have permission to list the searches.  A user with the Power User role should have the capability.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well I am admin on the Splunk server and have the right permissions. Also using a simple python script, I can get the list but not with C# Splunk.client.
So The end point is correct. 

Maybe I’m not doing this properly:
var service = new Service(new Uri("https://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:8089/services/saved/searches"));
await service.LogOnAsync(u, p);


and then both 
var savedsearches = service.SavedSearches.count;

and 

var savedsearches = service.SavedSearches.GetAllAsync();

return null

Comment: I'm not familiar with the C# SDK, but it looks like you're mixing access methods.  The `/services/saved/searches` REST call should be made using a normal HTTP GET request.  AIUI, the SavedSearches class and methods in the SDK apply to individual searches.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax issue. This is the correct way.
var savedSearches = service.SavedSearches;
await savedSearches.GetAllAsync();

Thank you guys.